# What is the difference between Mollify and Placate?

Tags: differences

I am learning the GRE Vocabulary. so both are explained as:
appease someone's anger or anxiety, make someone less angry.

Difference?

Answer (score 3):

When the word mollify is used, the stress is on soothing hostile or angry feelings, usually with words.  "I mollified my wife by talking gently to her."  "The negotiator mollified the terrorist by speaking calmly to him."

The word placate is used when we want to stress soothing antagonism or anger by giving a compliment or making a concession.  "I placated my wife by telling her what a great job she did at the sale."  "I placated my boss by admitting that he was correct in not believing the client's damage report."

The goal of both is to reduce anger.  They do it in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

One of the great things about English is that we often have several words for the same thing. This is because our language has Latin, French, Germanic and Greek roots.

> mollify (v.)
>
> late 14c., "to soften (a substance)," from Old French mollifier or
>   directly from Late Latin mollificare "make soft, mollify" from
>   mollificus "softening," from Latin mollis "soft" (see melt (v.)) +
>   root of facere "to make" (see factitious). Transferred sense of
>   "soften in temper, appease, pacify" is recorded from early 15c.
>   Related: Mollified; mollifying.
>
> placate (v.)
>
> 1670s, a back-formation from placation or else from Latin placatus
>   "soothed, quiet, gentle, calm, peaceful," past participle of placare
>   "to calm, appease, quiet, soothe, assuage," related to placere "to
>   please" (see please). Related: Placated; placating; placatingly.
>
> [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://%3EOnline%20Etymology%20Dictionary)

**Answer**

1. The main difference between the words (apart of course from the fact that they look and sound different) is in the way that they found their way into English.
2. For differences in definition, consult any good dictionary. It would go against ELU guidelines merely to quote dictionaries here.
3. If you are interested in usage statistics then [Google ngram: placate,mollify](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=placate%2Cmollify&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplacate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmollify%3B%2Cc0) shows that the popularity of these words (as measured by ngram) swapped over completely in the late 1890s. These days 'placate' is used 2 or 3 times more often than 'mollify'.
4. That same ngram allows you to follow the links at the bottom of the page to see actual usage in published works.

Comment: I've never noticed the verbal/action distinction (that's not to say it isn't real, though).  To add to this answer: mollify is often used when talking about children or people of lower social rank, while placate is often used when talking about people of higher social status.

Comment: LOL. I was going to say that "placate" often involves a quid-pro-quo, whereas "mollify" can be merely "talking someone down".

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=say+to+placate%2Cdo+to+placate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csay%20to%20placate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20to%20placate%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TimRomano- I agree. I think of *to mollify* as to calm *in spite of the agitation* while *to placate* is  *to please* by *doing something* about the agitation.

Comment: How in the world does this answer help Giorgi understand the difference between the words?

Comment: @michael_timofeev - You have a point. I'll edit my answer.